# Point is chosen inside the square, find angle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Inside the square $MNPK$ point $O$ in such a way that $MO:ON:OP =1:2:3$. Find $\angle MON$.
I tried to solve this problem with vectors, but I couldn't find coordinates of point $O$. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Hint: consider the reflections of $P$ with respect to the sides of $MNP$ and the fact that $45^\circ=\arctan 1=\arctan(1/2)+\arctan(1/3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A,B,C$ be the reflections of $O$ with respect to $PN,PM,MN$.
We have $\widehat{BMC}=\widehat{BPA}=90^\circ$ and $\widehat{CNA}=180^\circ$.
The sides of $ABC$ follow the proportion $$AB:AC:BC=\sqrt{2}\,OP:2\,ON:\sqrt{2}\,OM=3\sqrt{2}:4:\sqrt{2}$$
hence by the inverse Pythagorean theorem $\widehat{BCA}=90^\circ$ and
$$\widehat{MON}=\widehat{MCA}=\widehat{MCB}+\widehat{BCA}=45^\circ+90^\circ=\color{red}{135^\circ}.$$

[image]

Comment: That's a beautiful solution :D

Answer (score 1):

Station the square so that $M$ is the origin and $N$ lies along the positive $x$-axis. Assume the side of the square is $a$, which we will rescale so that $MO = 1$ and then4 $ON = 2$ and $OP = 3$. Let $O$ be located at $(x,y)$ then length of $MO$ implies
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1^2
$$
and length of $ON$ implies
$$
(a-x)^2 + y^2 = 2^2.
$$
Write down the implication of length of $OP$ and solve 3 equations in 3 unknowns to find $a,x,y$. You can then find the angle, for example, from the law of cosines.

Comment: Shouldn't RHS of second equation be 4?

Comment: @NikaChelidze of course, thanks for pointing out. Please feel free to change directly next time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to solve it.

Comment: How did you make the question ? or from some book?

Comment: I don't know exactly, it has been posted somewhere in the group.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Apply the Pythagorean theorem to establish the system of three equations

\begin{align}
x^2+y^2=4,\>\>\>\>\> x^2+(a-y)^2=1,\>\>\>\>\> (a-x)^2+y^2=9 
\end{align}

The 2nd and 3rd equations lead to $y=\frac{a^2+3}{2a}$ and $x=\frac{a^2-5}{2a}$, respectively. Plug them into the 1st equation to get $a^4 - 10a^2 +17=0$, which yields $a^2 =5+2\sqrt2$. Then, use the cosine rule for the triangle OMN to obtain

$$\cos\angle MON = \frac{OM^2+ON^2-a^2}{2|OM||ON|} = \frac{1+4-(5+2\sqrt2)}{2\cdot 1\cdot2}=-\frac{\sqrt2}2$$

Thus, $\angle MON =135^\circ$.